# Membership Status not updating beyond Grace to Expired

Tags: civimember

The Grace status is set to end 2 years after Membership End Date. At that point the Expired status should kick in. The Grace status is activated correctly at Membership End Date, but that status is NOT ending at the "after 2 years" mark.

The Scheduled Job for updating membership status is executing OK.

Some of our memberships are now 3 years or more past their End Date - does the system recognise those old dates and update status accordingly? Or should these be manually overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there's a misconfiguration of your Membership Status Rules.

Please review them at **Administer menu >> CiviMember >> Membership Status Rules**.  Pay special attention to the Grace and Expired rules, especially to the Start Date Adjustment and End Date Adjustment.

If you're not sure how to interpret what you're seeing, feel free to edit your question to include screenshots.

Comment: Not sure what version of civi you are on Grant, but more recent ones should now show the Start, End and Adjustments on the Member Status screen. These used not to show and you would have to look in each one to figure if you had an overlap or gap in your rules, eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/member/membershipStatus?reset=1

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved by having Grace status End Date Adjustment set to 24 months after the membership end date. The Expired status was left with a Start Date of 2 years after the membership end date. For some reason if the two timings were set to be the same (i.e. 2 years or 24 months) the Expired status never kicked in.

Comment: that sounds weird and if replicable then i would consider it a bug.